# Javascript - Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: javascript, html, firebase-realtime-database

```
I want to display all the enteries in the job child below.
```

[image: Database]
     in the format below

[image: display]

```
 <div class="container positions">
 <h2>Job Openings</h2>
 <ul>

    <li class="pos-card" id="Jobcontainer">

  </div>

</ul>
</div>

function gotData(data) { 

var jobs = data.val();
var keys = Object.keys(jobs);

var container = document.getElementById('Jobcontainer');

for (var i = 0; i<keys.length; i++) {
var k = keys[i];
var newCard = `

 <li class="pos-card" id="Jobcontainer">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="title">`+ jobs[k].JobTitle + `</div>
    // <div class="dept">jobs[k].</div>
    <div class="date">April 21</div>
    <div class="refer">Refer</div>
  </div>
  <ul class="desc"> 
    <li>`+ jobs[k].JobSummary + `</li>

  </ul>
</li>`;

container.innerHTML += newCard;

}
}
```

it keep returning this error and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.
   TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.keys ()
    at gotData (Jobboard.html:136)
does anyone know what how to fix this?

Comment: what is `data.val()'? Please share the object

Comment: Can you turn this into a working snippet? It's impossible to help without seeing what your data variable looks like in gotData looks like

Comment: Ever solve this?